# Should I include my custom component's root element in the accompanying layout file when inflating and using <merge>?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-inflate

Currently I have this custom component (just the outline for brevity) that inflates its associated layout file:

```
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

public class MyComponent extends ConstraintLayout {

  public MyComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_component, this);
  }
}
```

This is the currently associated layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valueMainText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valueSubText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unitText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</merge>
```

Is my understanding correct that, when placed inside `activity_main.xml`, the final view hierarchy in that case will be:

```
- SomeLayout (MainActivity)
  - ConstraintLayout (MyComponent)
    - TextView
    - TextView
    - TextView
```

...or will I need to include my custom component's root element in the layout file as well, with something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/valueMainText"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          />
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/valueSubText"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          />
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/unitText"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</merge>
```

...to achieve this?

Comment: It kinda depends on what you're going for, but in the case, the answer is likely no, the `<ConstraintLayout>` is redundant. In the first setup, those `TextView`s will be added directly to your `MyComponent`, and their layout will be controlled by it. In the second one, those `TextView`s are inside another `ConstraintLayout`, and that whole thing will be a single child in `MyComponent`. I'd also mention that, if your custom `View` is just a few `TextView`s laid out simply, `ConstraintLayout` is likely overkill. You're probably better off subclassing, e.g., `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc.

Comment: @MikeM. Okay, so my initial understanding of the final hierarchy was correct then. And fair enough about the overkill. I'm still experimenting with the layout and relative positioning of my component's child elements, one of which needs auto-sizing text, and still unsure about the final design and responsiveness (new to android dev and not comfortable with it's capabilities yet), but I think you are probably right. Thank you for your valuable input!

Comment: Oh, yeah, I kinda misread how you were asking that. Yep, that first one is exactly right, and is usually what you want to do for compound `View`s like this. Anyhoo, glad I could help. Cheers!